# Is there anyway of marking in a method signature it should return a subtype of a particular type

Tags: scala, types

I can't understand why this doesn't compile:

```
abstract class Animal {}

class Duck extends Animal {}

object Main {
  def fooBar[T <: Animal ]():T = {
    return new Duck()
  }
}
```

Why do I get the compile error that:

> Required: T
>
> Found: Duck

Doesn't `T <: Animal` mean I just need to return a sub-type of `Animal`? & Duck is a Subtype? This is something I've been having allot of trouble understanding. Is there anyway of marking in a method signature it should return a subtype of a particular type?

Comment: `def fooBar(): Animal = new Duck()` doesn't work for you?

Comment: Can you explain what is your use case? I believe the already provided answers do a great job explaining why this doesn't work. But, I have the feeling that they are insufficient for you, because they probably do not solve your real problem. However, to be able to answer that, we would need to know about that.

Comment: Yeah I don’t really have a use case, I’m just having fun playing around with Scala, doing crazy stuff and failing haha. I just kind of thought there would be something like this to feed the Scala compiler more info and see what it will do. You know when you add a list of Dogs and a list of Cats you get back a list of Animal? Probably not related to this but just exploring.

Comment: @Snickers3192 You should tag someone when answering lol, you were lucky that I just decided to recheck this. Anyways, as stated in the comments what you want to achieve is in the general case not possible. You usually have four cases: 1. You want to be able to change returned object without affecting user code, that is the principle of subtyping, you just promise to return some super type and you can return any subtype of that. 2. You want the code to behave differently according to the type asked by the user, you can solve that with a **typeclass**.

Comment: 3. You want to return this specific type, like all animals have a `rename` method that return a copy of they with the name changed, so if I have a `Dog` I want another `Dog`, you can achieve that using **F-Bounded** polymorphism but usually a **typeclass** is a better approach. 4. You want a different output given an static input like `def getAnimalByIndex[A <: Animal](idx: Int): T = if (idx == 0) Dog else Cat`, and this can only be called where `idx` is a compile time constant, thus if I call `getAnimalByIndex(0)` I expect the result to be of type `Dog`, this will be possible in **Scala 3**.

Comment: _(I believe you can achieve that fourth case in **Scala 2** using **macros**, but I do not have any experience with that)_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Doesn't `T <: Animal` mean I just need to return a sub-type of `Animal`?

No. It means you have to return a `T`, chosen by the caller of your method. The caller is constrained to make this a subtype of `Animal`, but it could be a `Duck`, a `Dog` or a `Cat`.

You cannot just return a `Duck`, because the caller may have wanted a `Cat`.

Without some extra parameter to tell you what should be returned, the only way to implement this would be to return `Nothing`, i.e. throw an exception, return `null` (but don't do that in Scala) or never return at all.

> I just need to return a sub-type of `Animal`

If you want that, the return type should be declared as `Animal`.

You can always return a `Duck` when an `Animal` is required.

> why I cannot specify you can return a subtype of Animal but not an Animal itself!

There is no way you can specify this in the type system. And there should not really be a need for it either. If you say you need an `Animal`, everything that implements the interface defined by that is supposed to be good enough.

Possible "workarounds":

- make `Animal` an `abstract` class. Then there cannot be any instance of `Animal` itself, and all instances will be sub-class instances.
- have another `trait` and declare the type as `ActualAnimal` or `Animal with ActualImplementation`. But it would be extra work on your part to add this `trait` where needed (and make sure you don't add it to `Animal`)

Comment: What if Animal wasn’t abstract and I want whoever is overriding some method to return a subtype of Animal, because if they were to return just an Animal, let’s say the universe would  end ( ; so I can’t allow their code to compile! Ha no it’s really just for my own understanding why I cannot specify you can return a subtype of Animal but not an Animal itself!? I know that a sub type of Animal is an Animal but an Animal itself is simply an Animal, not a subtype of Animal, or is that incorrect somehow?

Answer (score 2):

Could you please explain your problem?

Current signature `def fooBar[T <: Animal ]():T` basically says 
"whatever type of animal a user asks for I can create an animal of exactly that type".

This function can't have reasonable implementations.

Comment: There is literally no problem, just purely trying to understand type bounds. This is just something I intuitively felt like I would be able to express, wether or not it had value or not, probably doesn’t sound like it based on these answers, but nevertheless thought it might be possible.

Comment: A rule of thumb: you never need `<:` type bounds unless you are doing shapeless-like stuff. 99% of the cases are covered by either normal parametric polymorphism (`fooBar[T]`), oldschool OOP (`fooBar() : Animal`) or typeclass-restricted polymorphism (`fooBar[T : Animal](): T`).

Comment: @simpadjo I disagree, I found `<:` very useful I use it a lot in my code and have never used **Shapeless** directly, and most of my code is written on a **FP** style using **typeclasses** for most of my things. I have also found the `<:<` **generalized type constraint** very useful.

Answer (score 1):

You want to do something like this:

```
abstract class Animal {}

class Duck extends Animal {}

object Main extends App{

    def fooBar[T <: Animal](animal:T): T = {
      animal
    }
    println(fooBar[Animal](new Duck))
    println(fooBar[Duck](new Duck))
}
```

Comment: That is not very useful though. Could just call `identity` instead.

Comment: Agree, that is not useful at all, but I think he wanted to getting it to compile to now do the logic he wanted